# Javascript reset object inside array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the below JS code in my Ember app that gets called;

```
myPanels.accordionPanels = [];
myPanels.accordionPanels.push({
    panel: {
        name: "my-grid",
        type: 'comp',
        props: [{
            key: 'elementId',
            value: "myCustomId"
        }]
    }
});
```

So as you can see, I start by setting myPanels.accordionPanels = [] every time and then push the object.

However, I got the following error

> Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in
>   use: myCustomId

So I am assuming that the object inside is not getting reset & it is able to find the earlier created "myCustomId".

Am I resetting the array (or rather the object inside it) correctly ?

Comment: Don't know much about the internals of ember.js, but if you do `myPanels.accordionPanels.length = 0;` instead of `myPanels.accordionPanels = [];`, does it make a difference?

Comment: If `accordionPanels` is already an array you can call `.clear()` on it.

Comment: So does doing myPanels.accordionPanels = [] not clear the inside contents of the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am able to push values using:

```
accordionPanels = [];
accordionPanels.push({
    panel: {
        name: "my-grid",
        type: 'comp',
        props: [{
            key: 'elementId',
            value: "myCustomId"
        }]
    }
});
```

make sure myPanels.accordionPanels doesn't have any prototype associated with it.
Try to inspect its value as:

```
myPanels.accordionPanels = [];
console.log(myPanels.accordionPanels); // see if it has values.
```

You can delete value using :

```
delete myPanels.accordionPanels PROTOTYPE
```